# Optimization of PostgreSQL query with filtering by counts

Tags: postgresql, optimization, aggregate

Is there a way to optimize such a query in PostgreSQL 9.5, 9.6?

```sql
SELECT x FROM (
    SELECT x,count(x) cnt FROM very_big_table WHERE (conditions) GROUP BY x
) sub
WHERE cnt > 10
```

Indexes to all `WHERE` conditions and `x` is obvios. Any other suggestions?

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `HAVING()` clause which is used exactly for this purposes (filters on aggregated columns) :

```
SELECT t.x,count(t.x) as cnt
FROM YourTable t
WHERE < >
GROUP BY t.x
HAVING count(t.x) > 10
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I do not see any performance change.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no way to speed up this query but to work on `WHERE` expression